# Android / Eclipse - Is it possible to use one device to mimic another device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt, eclipse-adt

I have had one or two [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) crash reports for my app when it has been run by a user on a budget device.

I know I can create an emulator for the device in Android Virtual Device Manager, but I find these emulators painfully slow to work with and am hoping there is a better alternative other than going out and buying the same phone as the user's.

So I would like to know if it is possible to configure my setup - maybe via Eclipse or by changing my actual phone settings - that will allow me to mimic the user's device?

The most important thing I would like to change is the available heap size.

NB - My device is a Samsung Galaxy S4 and the user's device is a (lower spec) HTC Desire C.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an app to tweak the Dalvik VM settings. There are several apps that let an advanced user to change the maximum heap size for all applocations running on the system. You can put  a cap on heap being used by every single VM instance to simulate HTC desire C heap size which I guess should be 32MB.

One of those apps are discussed here :

https://ryanolson.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/test-how-changing-the-max-amount-of-memory-per-vm-heap-can-effect-your-rom-cyanogen/

Comment: Not sure I like the look of that route... I think I will have to splash out on another device. :-/

Comment: You just can't buy a new cell phone everytime you get a crash report. But it is a good practise to have three phones: low-end. Mid-range, and high-so! Always have a 7" and 10.1" tablet too. That will cover almost all situations.

Comment: I wasn't planning to buy a new phone for each crash report / I just need a practical way of testing of testing on smaller heaps. That said, I'm just moving from Eclipse to Android Studio and am having a bit more joy with the emulators now, so they may suffice for the time being. Thanks for your help, by the way. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Android studio is far better than Eclipse. Good choice.